# Drag Down Formula whilst retaining some values but change another

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I'm looking for assistance with a problem i'm having when using Excel. The best way to explain the problem i'm encountering is that i'm using the auto-fill drag down to copy and paste essentially a formula.. I'm currently using this function on sheet 1:

```
 =sum('Sheet2'!E2*Sheet3!B3+Sheet3!B2)
```

Now, when dragging down the formula it changes which is expected, but not my intended results. The formula changes to the following:

```
=sum('Sheet2'!E3*Sheet3!B4+Sheet3!B3)
=sum('Sheet2'!E4*Sheet3!B5+Sheet3!B4)
```

My intended result is to have one reference cell change, but keep the last two in the formula the same reference as such:

```
 =sum('Sheet2'!E2*Sheet3!B3+Sheet3!B2)
 =sum('Sheet2'!E3*Sheet3!B3+Sheet3!B2)
 =sum('Sheet2'!E4*Sheet3!B3+Sheet3!B2)
 =sum('Sheet2'!E5*Sheet3!B3+Sheet3!B2)
```

With the intended first row populated with the formulas:

```
=sum('Sheet2'!E2*Sheet3!B3+Sheet3!B2)
=sum('Sheet2'!F2*Sheet3!C3+Sheet3!C2)   
=sum('Sheet2'!G2*Sheet3!D3+Sheet3!D2)   
=sum('Sheet2'!H2*Sheet3!E3+Sheet3!E2)   
=sum('Sheet2'!I2*Sheet3!F3+Sheet3!F2)   
=sum('Sheet2'!J2*Sheet3!G3+Sheet3!G2)   
=sum('Sheet2'!K2*Sheet3!H3+Sheet3!H2)   
=sum('Sheet2'!L2*Sheet3!I3+Sheet3!I2)
```

as the drag down formula changes from row to row, the last two references need to remain the same on sheet 3, but sheet 2 change as the row increases, so

```
'Sheet2'!E3
'Sheet2'!E4
'Sheet2'!E5
'Sheet2'!E6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `$` symbol before the portions that you don't want to change, such as:

```
=sum('Sheet2'!E2*Sheet3!B$3+Sheet3!B$2)
```

Comment: Note, sometimes these are referred to as fixed references. However if you delete or add rows on those sheets, Excel will adjust them.  If you really want to fix them permanently, then you need to use `INDIRECT`.